# Best options to host my asmx web service on machine not having IIS

Tags: iis, asmx

We have a requirement where we need to have some web services running on a server machine but it does not have IIS available. I came across this article on running asmx without IIS and many other sites/blogs have mentioned this article as well.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx

Could somebody offer alternatives to above to run asmx web services without IIS installed?

Other option i could find was Cassini - http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/

Comment: Probably you can ask this question in SuperUser to get some good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Azure!  That is precisely what it was designed for...  it’s cheap and reliable!